# Ionic is not building iOS app because of @ionic-cloud

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I've a problem, I'm working with my app and now I'm working with notifications. The thing is that I'm working on that for a long week and I cannot fix it.

Notifications are working in Android, but with iOS is not. Plus, my Ionic cannot build the app in iOS, the terminal is working with the message "Running command" for hours and nothing happens. After some days checking what could be the problem, I found that this is happening every time I install @ionic-cloud, without this I can build perfectly a iOS app, but whenever I install that, the process get frozen in the part of "Running command".

I'm using Ionic 3, even my app is based in Ionic 2. I'm using MacBook.

If anyone could help me, I will be really thankful!!

Comment: Did you add the CloudModule in app.module.ts? `... imports: [ CloudModule.forRoot(cloudSettings), ...], ...` (see https://docs.ionic.io/setup.html#configuration)

Comment: @pwagner Yes, I did.